# What tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(output_vector), axis, keep_dims=True) is doing?

Tags: tensorflow

What is this function is doing I am not getting.

`def squash(output_vector, axis=-1): 
norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(output_vector), axis, keep_dims=True)
return output_vector * norm / ((1 + norm) * tf.sqrt(norm + 1.0e-10))`

This portion :
**tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(output_vector), axis, keep_dims=True)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look it line by line:

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
squared = tf.square(X)
# Each element of the input vector will be put to the power of 2
# [[ 1  4  9]
#  [16 25 36]]
reduced_0_keepdims = tf.reduce_sum(squared, axis=0, keepdims=True)
# Elements will be summed on the specified axis and
# by setting keepdims=True the dimensions of the output tensor
# will remain the same
# [[17 29 45]]
reduced_1 = tf.reduce_sum(squared, axis=1)
# Elements will be summed on the specified axis and the tensor will be reduced
# [14 77]
```